# npm start is starting the server.js not my React app, how can I use it to start my app?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, nodemon, npm-start

So I was having this issue of node not restarting the server when there changes made on the server.js file. I fixed it by editing the package.json file. However, once fixed, the npm start command starts the server.js file:  `` [nodemon] starting `node server.js ``

How do I start my react app then? npm start was the command I used before

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most probably your set your package.json file to

```
"scripts": {
"start": "nodemon server.js",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

},

Change your server package.json to something like this:

```
 "scripts": {
"server": "nodemon server.js",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
```

*then run the command*

> npm run server *--this will start your server.js*

Comment: Thanks a lot! This worked like a charm and I also see where I went wrong, I made start "start" command to start the server and expected it to start the react environment.

Answer (score 0):

Nodemon has nothing to do with the client-side(React app). So, before running `npm-start`:

1. Make sure you are in the correct directory `cd [directory-name]`
2. It's better to separate your front-end and back-end in a separate folder